# Notepad++ search result window does not respond on keyboard commands

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, mouse

As you might know, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ALT+SPACE</kbd> opens a popup menu, which you can use to move, minimise or maximise the window you're working with.

Using this popup menu on Notepad++ in general is working fine (although I believe this is Windows technology, not notepad++ specific), as you can see here:

Appearance of the popup menu after hitting <kbd>ALT+SPACE</kbd>:

[image]

The effect on Notepad++ (the appearance of the "Movement mouse cursor" in the heading of the Notepad++ window):

[image]

This allows me to move Notepad++ window around, using the keyboard (left, right, up and down arrows).

When I try this with the search result window inside Notepad++, this doesn't work (it only reacts on mouse events, not on the keyboard).

I'm currently working on Notepad++ version v8.5.7, but the same behaviour is also seen on version v8.5.4.

Is this a known Notepad++ bug and are there any plans to get this solved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu invoked by Alt+Space is called the application menu and is
a Windows option that works only on entire application windows.
The menu has default entries, as in your screenshot, but the application
can add additional entries inside (which Notepad++ doesn't do).
You probably refer to the Move option.

This is a Windows option and a Windows menu, so it is not relevant to
the internal layout of Notepad++ windows.

The layout changes in Notepad++ are very limited.
You may change the color theme, the toolbar, the menu and also
keyboard shortcuts, but that's about all you can do.

Comment: Are you aware of any plans of improving Notepad++ behaviour in that sense?

Comment: I'm not a Notepad++ developer. You could raise this as a feature request in their forums, and you might get a response, positive or negative.